# PHP Curl Error when using SSL

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

I am trying to use the WHMCS API to connect a third party script to it. I have created the third party's script as follows, however, when I try to connect to my site using HTTPS, I get this error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

If I use HTTP, I get a 404 error. The code is as follows (and yes, that is my actual domain, since I figured the SSL's specifics might matter):

```
$email = $_GET["email"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && strlen($password) > 0) {
    $postfields["username"] = $apiusername;
    $postfields["password"] = $apipassword;
    $postfields["action"] = "validatelogin";
    $postfields["email"] = $email;
    $postfields["password2"] = $password;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tfdidesign.com/accounts/includes/api.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
        echo(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);     
    $data = explode(";",$data);
    foreach ($data AS $temp) {
        $temp = explode("=",$temp);
        $results[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
    }
}
else
    die("INVALID_CREDENTIALS");
```

Answer (score -2):

Define the ssl version for your curl(it can be 2 or 3):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

Also try to use this one:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Comment: The page infinitely times out now.

Comment: Extremely insecure. From PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): **`Setting it [CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.
`**